# Undefined control sequence \centerdot

Tags: symbols, characters

I am getting an "Undefined control sequence" error when I try to use the

```
\centerdot
```

command, even though that command is shown in many references as the way to insert a centered dot. What is the problem?

Comment: Please try `\usepackage{amssymb}`

Answer (score 4):

You might need `amssymb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\centerdot$
\end{document}
```